# locust has no workers

Tags: docker-compose, apple-m1, locust

I'm trying to start locust using docker-compose on Macbook M1:

- the issue:

  - it starts but there is no workers
- expected behaviour:

  - should have one worker
- logs:

  - no error logs
- code to reproduce it:

```
version: '3.3'

services: 
  master_locust:
    image: locustio/locust:master
    ports:
      - "8089:8089"
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/mnt/locust
    command: -f /mnt/locust/locustfile.py --master
    depends_on:
      - worker_locust

  worker_locust:
    image: locustio/locust:master
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/mnt/locust
    command: -f /mnt/locust/locustfile.py --worker --master-host=master_locust
```

- commands:

  - docker-compose up master_locust
  - docker-compose up --scale worker_locust=4 master_locust
- screenshot:

  - [image]

Comment: What do the worker logs say?

Comment: Also, dont use :master unless you really need the bleeding edge.